# checking an array java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

I am using a 2d array like a map, I have a set point, x and y and I need to check the surrounding areas(+1) for three objects, food, object and space. I thought about using map[x+1][y+1] like shown below, however I would have to repeat this status many times.

```
if (map[x+1][y+1] == Item.O)
{
    System.out.println("Object is in the way.");
}

if (map[x+1][y+1] == Item.F)
{
    System.out.println("Food is in the way.");
}
```

Is there any other way to do this, I know there is a switch statement however I don't think this will work. Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: `Item` is an `enum`?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to add that.

Comment: It looks like you would just want a nested for loop for this, to go from x-1 to x+1 and y-1 to y+1, just make sure to skip over (x, y) if need be

Comment: What do you want to do? Use one loop?

Comment: Yeah that might be the best option, im just trying to write it better then multiple If statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumed that `Item` is an `enum`, you could indeed use a `switch` statement:

```
switch(map[x+1][y+1]) {
   case Item.O : System.out.println("Object is in the way."); break;
   case Item.F : System.out.println("Food is in the way."); break;
   ...
}
```

However, a much more flexible solution would be not to store an `enum` in your array, but real objects which implement a common interface which provides the required methods. Then implement different classes which implement the different behaviour of your objects.

Your class hierarchy could look like this:

```
interface PrintText {
    void printText();
}

class Food implements PrintText {
    public void printText() {
       System.out.println("Food is in the way.");
    }
}

class SomeObject implements PrintText {
    public void printText() {
       System.out.println("Object is in the way.");
    }
}
```

You can then initialize your array similar to this:

```
// initialize array
PrintText[][] map = new PrintText[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
map[0][0] = new Food();
map[0][1] = new SomeObject();
...
```

And later on call the method like that, without any `switch` or `if` statement - polymorphism takes care of it:

```
// call the method
map[x+1][y+1].printText();
```

On a side note, do not use raw arrays. Use a collection class like [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

Comment: This solution is good. I also think he is going to use the method for collision checking, so it would be a good idea to return a boolean.

Comment: Thanks, enum and Items have been such a pain, ill see how I can add this to my code:)

Comment: Glad if it helped :) Your problem simply **calls** for using polymorphism to implement the different behaviour of Food and other objects in different classes with some common interface - with that, you can always add other objects at a later time with low impact on existing code